# C# VkNet авторизация

Tags: c#, вконтакте, vknet

После выполнения этого кода кнопка залипает и ничего не происходит.

```
VkApi vkApi = new VkApi();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        vkApi.Authorize(new ApiAuthParams()
        {
            Login = "***",
            Password = "***",
            ApplicationId = 7644324,
            Settings = Settings.All
        });
        if(vkApi.IsAuthorized == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("+");
        }

    }
```

Возможно ожидает двухфакторную авторизацию? если да то как сделать

Comment: Ну а на аккаунте есть двухфактор?

Comment: да вроде как и нету

Comment: • 7644324 - это `appId`. Он точно верный?

Comment: • Точно ли корректна пара логина и пароля?

Comment: Это верные данные

Comment: Обновил ответ...

Comment: Используй `AuthorizeAsync`

Answer (score 1):

Двухфакторная авторизация:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var api = new VkApi();

    api.Authorize(new ApiAuthParams
    {
        ApplicationId = 123456,
        Login = "Login",
        Password = "Password",
        Settings = Settings.All,
        TwoFactorAuthorization = () =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Code:");
            return Console.ReadLine();
        }
    });

    Console.WriteLine(api.Token);
}
```

https://vknet.github.io/vk/authorize/

Если не сработает, то попробуйте получить токен через:
https://oauth.vk.com/token?grant_type=password&client_id=2274003&client_secret=hHbZxrka2uZ6jB1inYsH&username=PHONE_OR_MAIL&password=YOURPASSWORD&v=5.78

(поменяйте там поля на ваши логин и пароль).
С некоторых времен ВК запрещает выдавать полные права на токен.
Возможно при `Settings = Settings.All` происходит беда.

По этой ссылке можно получить токен с полными правами.
(Как это работает можете погуглить).

И далее ->

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var api = new VkApi();
    
    api.Authorize(new ApiAuthParams
    {
        AccessToken = "access_token"
    });
    Console.WriteLine(api.Token);
    var res = api.Groups.Get(new GroupsGetParams());

    Console.WriteLine(res.TotalCount);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Не сработало :( что можно предпринять? (Да и пароль никакой не приходит на телефон)

Comment: Хм, теперь без двухфакторной я могу получить токен, а вот с ней он уже не пропускает, нужно что-то придумать